# Calculate time diff by row in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table `tiket_event` like this, it store all events happen by changing status on each ticket

| ticket_id | status | gmt_update |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | OPEN | 1620000488 |
| T01 | IN_PROGRESS | 1620000588 |
| T02 | OPEN | 1620000499 |
| T01 | DONE | 1620000688 |
| T02 | CLOSE | 1620000599 |
| T01 | CLOSE | 1620000788 |

So now by mysql query, i want to group by ticket_id and calculate the amount of time between each status change,

for example `T01` is change status from `OPEN` to `IN_PROGRESS` in 100ms, and from `OPEN` to `DONE` in 200ms

The issue is that few statuses will be missing in some cases, like `T02`, it has only `OPEN` and `CLOSE` directly.

Could anybody suggest query for this case?

EDIT: Result i want, i can update query for timediff of any pair of statuses

| ticket_id | open_to_inprogress_timediff | open_to_done_timediff | open_to_close_timediff | done_to_close_timediff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 100 |
| T02 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 0 |

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: show what results you want for the sample data?

Comment: are those 4 the only statuses you care about or are there an arbitrary number of statuses?

Comment: We dont usually use ``string`` for status field.  You should use ``tinyint`` and another table or enum to contain unchange values cuz it wastes less space.

Comment: @ysth there is around 15 statues, i just simplified to let you got my case

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuyền, thanks, i knew this. just use string here for you guys to imagine usecase easier.

Comment: @ysth version is `5.7.14.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to hard-code which differences to look for.

```sql
SELECT ticket_id
     , MAX(CASE status WHEN 'IN_PROGRESS' THEN gmt_update END) -
       MIN(CASE status WHEN 'OPEN' THEN gmt_update END)
       AS open_to_inprogress_timediff
     , MAX(CASE status WHEN 'DONE' THEN gmt_update END) -
       MIN(CASE status WHEN 'OPEN' THEN gmt_update END)
       AS open_to_done_timediff
     , MAX(CASE status WHEN 'CLOSE' THEN gmt_update END) -
       MIN(CASE status WHEN 'OPEN' THEN gmt_update END)
       AS open_to_close_timediff
     , MAX(CASE status WHEN 'CLOSE' THEN gmt_update END) -
       MIN(CASE status WHEN 'DONE' THEN gmt_update END)
       AS done_to_close_timediff
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY ticket_id
 ORDER BY ticket_id
```